# Config Superset with SSO using Google OAuth API -- missing scope parameter?

Tags: python, google-oauth, apache-superset

I have been trying to login to Superset (including registering new user) using Google OAuth API, following this instruction: https://aungmt.medium.com/superset-with-google-oauth-3ba7a1c1f459

All my search results shows me this config supposed to work. However, as soon as I click login button, I'm getting a `Error 400: invalid_request Missing required parameter: scope`. I quadruple checked my *superset_config.py* and it has `'scope': 'openid email profile'` in it.

Anyone could shine a light on this?

Comment: Its a lot easier to help you if you include your code in your question without seeing your code its just guessing but i would look for something called scope in your code and figuer out why its not being sent.

Comment: @DaImTo my bad, I should totally include my config. I got it to work, the bottom line is the tutorial I quoted uses "request_token_params" rather than "client_kwargs" in the config, along some other keys that's not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received some feed backs from Superset Slack channel. ***@Daniel Gaspar***

I guess the tutorial I found online were all for older version of Superset. Some of the key names in the config did not match current documentation. Below is my working config as of **Superset v0.38.0**

```
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
{
    'name': 'google',
    'icon': 'fa-google',
    'token_key': 'access_token',
    'remote_app': {
        'api_base_url': 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/',
        'client_kwargs': {
            'scope': 'openid email profile'
        },
        'request_token_url': None,
        'access_token_url': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        'authorize_url': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
        'client_id': '###GOOGLE_KEY###',
        'client_secret': '###GOOGLE_SECRET###'
    }
}
]
```

Comment: I had to add `'jwks_uri': "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs"` inside `remote_app` to make it work.